# How to set URL query parameters in Visual Studio on Start Page

Tags: javascript, url, visual-studio-2012, parameters, start-page

Rewording this as I just learned that 'answering your own question on SO is ENCOURAGED', but I didn't use the correct procedure.  This is he Jeopardy version.

I'm building a Javascript/HTML5 web site using Visual Studio 2012 for Web.  I need to feed in a query parameter to the selected Start page.  VS Web allows you to right-click on an html page and select 'Set As Start Page', but no way to set start options.  How can I set query options on the launch of my web page from the debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *right-click on the project* and go to **'Start Options...'**.

In the **Start Options dialog** you can add query parameters to the **'Specific page:'** option.  The drop-down in Specific Page allowed you to modify the URL to add your own parameters.  E.g. *myStartPage.html?myParameter=3*

You can't use the Start URL option with the internal debugger since since you have to specify 'localhost:port/myStartPage?myParameter=3'. VS is unhappy with this and ends up with a 404 page.